# MS Teams: Compose extension is accessible from group conversation despite groupchat not being in the manifest.json scopes

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I am working in a Microsoft Teams bot. I have defined a compose extension of 'action' type and 'message' context. I want my bot to be available only within channel and personal chat. So, I defined my manifest.json accordingly.

manifest.json

```
"bots": [
    {
      "botId": "@IS_AZURE_BOT_ID@",
      "scopes": [
        "team",
        "personal"
      ],
.....
.....


"commands": [
        {
          "id": "submitIdeaMessageExtension",
          "title": "Submit Idea v3",
          "type": "action",
          "context": ["message"],
          "description": "Submit selected message as idea",
          "initialRun": false,
          "fetchTask": true
        }
      ]
```

But the problem is I can still access this compose extension from group chat. As you can clearly see in the manifest I havn't defined groupChat scope in my manifest.json.

Please check the screenshot attached.
[image: screenshot]

The compose extension should not be accessed from group conversation. As it's not in groupChat scope.

Comment: We are able to repro that issue, we have raised bug for the same. We will inform you once we get any update.

Comment: @Sayali-MSFT thanks for taking this into cognizance. We are looking forward to the fix.

Comment: got the reply from engineering team that "the Message Extension works for all scopes by default, we should never allow developer to set scopes"